# How to access main class from subclass without passing a reference in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am building a typescript game where the main class needs to be accessible from anywhere in the game. I am trying to emulate a C# / Unity / Actionscript way of working with classes and instances.

I'd like to avoid the "modules/export" syntax since I find it somewhat counterintuitive (why even use classes if everything is a module?), but perhaps that is a lack of understanding on my part.

**game.ts**

```
class Game {
    private score:number = 0;

    constructor() {
        var t = new Tank();
        t.shootGun();
    }

    addScore(i:number){
        this.score += i;
    }
} 

// now we create an instance of our game
var g = new Game();
```

**tank.ts**

```
class Tank {
    constructor() {

    }

    shootGun() {
       // I want to call a function on the 'g' instance created above
       g.addScore("25");
    }
}
```

*My question is : how can tank (or any other instance running at some point in the game) call a function on the "g" instance that is created after main.ts is run?*

Comment: In this case, haven't you broken encapsulation? Why would `Tank` ever need to know about scores, let alone do anything with them? Shouldn't that be a responsibility of the `Game` class?

Comment: In this particular case, yes. But somehow somewhere some child might need to call a function of a parent class, or update data in a model. How would you approach this, without passing a reference around everywhere?

Comment: `Game` would need to act on the output of `Tank.shoot()`. Modifying `Game` within the `Tank` instance is a side effect and doing this could be considered an [anti-pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208828/passing-an-object-into-a-method-which-changes-the-object-is-it-a-common-anti) at least according the accepted answer there.

Comment: Also you can take my comments with a grain of salt. I really don't know a lot about game programming, much less how Unity handles classes and relationships between objects.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
class Tank {
    constructor(public g: Game) {

    }

    shootGun() {
        this.g.addScore(25);
    }
}

class Game {
    private score: number = 0;

    constructor() {
        var t = new Tank(this);
        t.shootGun();
    }

    addScore(i: number) {
        this.score += i;
    }
} 

// now we create an instance of our game
var g = new Game();
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I was wondering how to do this without passing a reference. I find this cumbersome if a child has many child classes - then you have to keep passing the reference throughout an entire chain only because a deep child class needs it.